# Calling to a function doesn't work at times

Tags: php, database, user-defined-functions

In a project I am currently working on I want to get data from a function in a class. thus I am calling that function from my main index file. however at the spot where I originally wanted to make the call I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function searchKlant()
> on array in N:\xampp\htdocs\Sylvia project\index.php:66  Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main} thrown in N:\xampp\htdocs\Sylvia project\index.php on line 66

However, if I use the same line of code:

```
$klantfor = $klant->searchKlant($_GET['k']);
```

in a different spot in the same code, I do get the needed result.
what makes it further interesting if I call the same function but this time in a different class it does work.

I would be gratefull if anyone would be able to help me in what is going wrong.
Thank you in advance

the main page code:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include 'custom/' . $class_name . '.class.php';
});

$klant = new Klant;
$invoice = new Invoice;

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['form'])){
    if($_POST['form']=="klant") {
       $klant->addKlant($_POST);
    } else if($_POST['form']=="invoice"){
       $invoice->addInvoice($_POST);
    }
}

$allklanten = $klant->getKlanten();
$allinvoice = $invoice->getInvoice();


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <?php include("components/header.php") ?>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <ul class="col-sm-4 list-unstyled">
                <?php
                    foreach($allklanten as $klant){
                        echo "<li><a href='?page=0&k=" . $klant['kID'] . "'>" . $klant['kVoornaam'] . " " . $klant['kAchter'] . "</a></li><br>";
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
                if ($_GET['page'] == 2) {
                    include("pages/klantadd.php");
                } else if ($_GET['page'] == 3) {
                    include("pages/invoiceadd.php");
                }
            }
        ?>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <?php
                if(isset($_GET['k'])){

                    $klantfor = $klant->searchKlant($_GET['k']);
                    $invoicefor = $invoice->searchInvoice($_GET['k']);

                    foreach ($klantfor as $klant){
                    echo "<h3>" . $klant['kVoornaam'] . " " . $klant['kAchter'] . "</h3>";}

                    echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Datum</th>
                                <th>test.class</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                          ";

                    foreach($invoicefor as $invoice){
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $invoice['iID'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $invoice['iDate'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }

                    echo "</tbody></table>";
                }
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

And the function in question:

```
public function searchKlant($target){
        $db = new Database();
        $db = $db->getConn();

        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM klant WHERE kID = ?");
        $statement->bind_param("i",$target);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->get_result();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $klant[] = $row;
        }
        $statement->close();
        $db->close();

        return $klant;
    }
```

Comment: because you overwrite `$klant` here: `foreach($allklanten as $klant)`

Comment: also overwriting at `foreach ($klantfor as $klant){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overwrite your instance `$klant` of class `Klant` here:

```
foreach($allklanten as $klant) {....
```

So change that to something else ($klantItem or so).

See this simple example:

```
<?php

$array = Array(1,2,3);

$v="a class";
foreach($array as $v) {
    echo $v;
}

echo "outside: ".$v;
// output: 'outside: 3' - so "a class" is overwritten.
```

Comment: to be honest I had to check myself whether $klant in foreach gets "global" - but since a controlstructure is not a seperate scope - it does.